# I'm trying to find execution time of my code, but its not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test how long a script which is embedded into html takes and how long an external javascript takes to execute.

Im trying:

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>External JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>(myFunction is stored in an external file called "myScript.js")</p>

<script src="myScript.js"></script>

<script>

var t0 = performance.now();
myFunction();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

no timing is being outputted.

Comment: You know that it is java code ? not javascript it just wont work

Comment: timing? did this execute first?

Comment: that really working ??

Comment: UPDATE sry...............

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsperf](https://jsperf.com) to test performace of your script and compare it with other or using node do [benchmark](https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark) test.